# What is the probability of pulling out at least 2 hearts consecutively, having 3 extractions with replacement out of a complete deck?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification

Here' my reasoning:

The total possible combinations are $52\cdot52\cdot52$; the combinations starting with $h_1h_1$ are $52$, with $h_1h_2$ are $52$, ... with $h_{13}h_{13}$ are $52$, so there should be $52\cdot13\cdot13$ ways to have the first 2 cards as hearts. Then regarding the possibility $CHH$ I thought the situation was symmetric; taking from it the doublecount of the $HHH$ I concluded the probability is $\dfrac{2\cdot52\cdot13\cdot13-13\cdot13\cdot13}{52\cdot52\cdot52}=\dfrac7{64}$

But this is not among the given options, what is my mistake? How to fix it?

Comment: I get ${}7/64$.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Oh. I thought it was wrong because it wasn't in the options! I see it must have been a typo in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oh. I thought it was wrong because it wasn't in the options! I see it must have been a typo in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm answering so that the question doesn't remain unanswered, once I can accept this)

The answer is correct, there was a typo in the question.

Comment: You can also compute the answer by computing the probability that there are two hearts followed by a non-heart, a non-heart followed by two hearts, or three hearts, which yields $$\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) + \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) = \frac{3}{64} + \frac{3}{64} + \frac{1}{64} = \frac{7}{64}$$

Comment: So why don't you click accept?

Comment: @GNUSupporter 2 days have to pass.